# Highchart yAxis Values

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

I have a Highchart Bar chart as mentioned below and its displaying some number values in yAxis according to the height of the chart. How can I add the following values [0, 40, 80, 120, 160, 200] and replace the auto populated values.

```
             $('#barchart').highcharts({
                     chart: {
                          type: 'column',
                          backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
                          height: 250
                     },

                     title: {
                          text: ''
                     },

                     subtitle: {
                          text: ''
                     },

                     xAxis: {
                          categories: [
                              'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
                          ],

                     },

                     yAxis: {
                          min: 0,
                          max: 200,

                          title: {
                               text: ''
                          },
                          gridLineWidth: 1,
                          gridLineColor: '#eaeaea'

                      },

                     tooltip: {
                          headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px; font-family:inherit">{point.key}</span><table>',
                          pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                               '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f}</b></td></tr>',
                          footerFormat: '</table>',
                          shared: true,
                          useHTML: true
                     },

                     legend: {
                          enabled: false
                     },

                     plotOptions: {
                          column: {
                               pointPadding: 0.2,
                               borderWidth: 0
                          }
                     },

                     credits: {
                          enabled: false
                     },

                     exporting: {
                          enabled: false    
                     },

                     series: [
                          {
                               name: 'Google',
                               data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 160.2, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
                          }, {
                               name: 'Yahoo',
                               data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]
                          }, {
                               name: 'Bing',
                               data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]
                          }, {
                               name: 'Other',
                               data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]
                          }
                     ],

                     colors: [
                          '#e33e3e', 
                          '#0671c7', 
                          '#049025', 
                          '#FFA206', 
                     ]
                });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P2Mv2/19/

Answer (score 1):

Use tickInterval:

```
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 200,

            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            tickInterval: 40,
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            gridLineColor: '#eaeaea'

        },
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/U6NhV/

Answer (score 1):

You can use tickPositions / tickPositioner

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions

or set min/max values as manishie mentioned.